# How to display an object properties on the page from an array of objects in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a website that has a list of products when a user clicks on 'Add to cart' he adds a product to the card (product is saved in a Local Storage). I want to display a list of projects added to the card from the Local storage on my page, but all I get is:
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]. How do I display the properties of these objects on my page? (I have a JSON file with the names, pictures, prices of the product, the data to display is coming from my JSON file)

Comment: You should probably loop through your localStorage item and then loop again through each object to show all the properties. But we don't know what your data looks like, so it's hard to say for sure. Please add the parsed JSON to your question.

Comment: you probably want to do `{{obj.someProp}}` instead of `{{obj}}`.

Comment: can you show your existing template?

Comment: @Lux yes, I already figured out that I need to loop through an array, and wrote an action for it, which works and shows name properties to the console like this:
showList(){
      let list = this.get('cart.items');
      list.forEach(item => { console.log(item.name); });
    },
and now i'm trying to figure out how to display it correctly in my hbs file, not in the console. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please show your existing `hbs` file.

Comment: Also have a look [into the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/looping-through-lists/)

Comment: @Lux https://imgur.com/a/MlxDQKY it looks like this, I know it's a pure mess, but I'm just starting out in Ember and not really familiar with all of the features

Comment: please *never* share code as pictures but edit your original question and add the code as code. You cann add codeblocks with 3 backticks (```) or by indenting it by 4 spaces

Comment: @Lux, I'm relatively new to Stackoverflow, so now I know how to do it, thank you and also thanks so much for the response to my question.

Comment: Sure, don't worry. We all started once. Also if a answer answers your question consider to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Lux, I actually have another question related to this one, if you don't mind. I have a separate route for my cart: /cart, and I want to display the products from the local storage there(name, price, etc). I imported the storage in my route and tried to do the following as a test 
`export default Route.extend({
cart: storageFor('cart'),
items: reads('cart.items'),
model(){    
    return this.get('cart.items').forEach(
    item => {console.log(item.price)
    console.log(item.name)});
}
});` and it works perfectly, but when I'm trying to make an hbs using #each, it doesn't really work

Comment: if you have another question please ask it as a seperate questions. Comments should be comments only. If you seek more interactive help maybe consider to join the ember community discord channel linked [here](https://emberjs.com/community/).

Comment: @Lux, got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cann access the properties inside the `{{#each}}` block:

```
{{#each cart.items as |item|}}
  {{item.name}}
{{/each}}
```

You *could* also `{{#each-in` to loop through all properties:

```
{{#each cart.items as |item|}}
  {{#each-in item as |name value|}}
    <div>{{name}}: {{value}}</div>
  {{/each-in}}
{{/each}}
```

but I would usually not recommend this because you dont just want to show *all* of them but specific ones and format them in specific ways to its better to be explicit here.

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to simply see the Json, put your json in **Json.stringify()**, and you will see the the key and values

**But i think you need the following solution:**

```js
var data = {product1: "A", product:"B", product3:"C"}
            
function renderData(){
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index)=>{
      concsole.log(key, date[key]);
    });
}
```

Hope the solution is what you expect.

Comment: He's talking about `ember`, so he needs the correct `hbs` template. He probably does not want to `console.log` the data but render it.